# fatal error LNK1118

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, fatal-error, dumpbin

When I build my dll the "fatal error LNK1118: syntax error in 'ENTRY' statement" occur in definition.def file.So please tell me how to write in the definition.def file.In somwhere I read about dumpbin.exe.Can I use it in this case.

- #define ENTRY   _stdcall
- typedef LONG  OKERR
  these are define in other header file.
  The definition.def file like this.
- LIBRARY "hello"
- EXPORTS
- OKERR ENTRY function1
- OKERR ENTRY function2

Comment: Can you post your existing definition file, so we have a chance to see what's going on?

Comment: LIBRARY "hello"
EXPORTS
OKERR ENTRY function1

Comment: when I build it fatal error occur.

Comment: Something like `EXPORTS function1` should be enough. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But now when I build the project this error occur. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol function1